# Generating input type programitaclly in Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a requirement where I need to identify the input type of a form based on the bean value.

The element bean has a property name, label, type, mandatory.

If the type value is "text", `<input type="text">` should get displayed on the page.

If type="File", `<input type="file">` should be displayed on the page.

My Bean:

```
    public class Element {
        private String name;
        private String label;
        private String type;
        private String mandatory;
        private String value;
    }

    Config JSON:

    {"input": [
        {
          "name": "file1",
          "label": "File 1",
          "type": "File",
          "mandatory": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "Indicator",
          "label": "Indicator",
          "type": "text",
          "mandatory": "true"
        }
      ]}
```

The Controller will read the JSON and populate a list of Element Objects.

On the UI, when I am trying to add the below code, it doesn't generate the input type as expected.

I am able to see the all the values when I used only below code:

```
<div th:each="element: ${accelerator_input}">
<p th:text="${element.label}" />
```

But when I am adding an input type in my code, it doesn't work.

```
    <div th:each="element: ${accelerator_input}">
                    <p th:text="${element.label}" />
                    <input type="${element.type}"  name=${element.name}
                        th:field="${element.value}" />
    </div>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Thymeleaf to process your attributes, they must be prefixed with `th:`.

```
<div th:each="element: ${accelerator_input}">
  <p th:text="${element.label}" />
  <input th:type="${element.type}" th:name="${element.name}" th:field="${element.value}" />
</div>
```